# Visual Studio 2013 and Oracle 11g express : how to connect?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g

I'm trying to reach my Oracle database through Visual Studio Server Explorer. I've installed Oracle 11g Express edition and I've downloaded the sql developer tool. By default, a "system user" is created and we've to give a password and I did it.

When it comes to connect to my DB via VS 2013, I choose the Oracle provider and I'm asked to enter the server name, the username and the password. I guess that the username and password are the system credentials but what about the server name? How can I find it? Is it XE by default? Because when I'm trying with that, I'm getting that error :

> **ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting an Oracle Net setup i.e. tnsnames.ora for clients and listener.ora for the server.

Use Oracle Net Manager to set these up.

Or simply use a thin driver and connect directly to the listener  (usually port 1521)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. However, as I'm pretty new with Oracle, I've installed the oracle developer tool for VS which I downloaded. So now I'm able to use the ODP.NET driver but when I'm entering my creditials, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the Oracle XE EZ Connect settings

1. Find C:\APEX\XE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora where the path is the path you used to install Oracle XE as its root.
2. Open with Notepad and look for the HOST, PORT and DEFAULT SERVICE LISTENER settings.  In this case, they are YOUR-HOST-NAME, 1521 and XE respectively.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YOUR-HOST-NAME)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

[Oracle Server Provider Settings In Visual Studio 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXhwp.png)

[Visual Studio Server Explorer w/XE Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfccu.png)